# Ionic typescript - How to search data from firebase by typing value of one of the field?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I would like to perform the search string by input field and query firebase database . below is my html and TS code but seem filtering not working. the serach function will return all the data and not order /filter by "unit no" .

eg. if search for "unit no =22" , the result should return the parcel data by "unit no =22" .

I not sure whether is my databse structuring problem or my code.

if i added this code

```
let result = this.postArray.filter(e=> e.unitno == this.getprofile.unitno)
```

May i know how to replace the ngFor* item ?

```
html :

<ion-item class="unitno">
      <ion-label stacked class="uni-label" position="stacked">Enter Your Unit No :</ion-label>
        <ion-input name="unitno" placeholder="unitno" type="text" [(ngModel)]="getprofile.unitno"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>


 <ion-row *ngFor="let item of postArray; let idx = index" class="text-content">
            <!-- <ion-col class="table-cell text-content-small" size="1">{{idx + 1}}</ion-col> -->
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.unitno}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.trackno}}</ion-col>
            <!-- <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.mydate}}</ion-col> -->
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">{{item.mydate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col class="table-cell" size="3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" (click)="receiveparcel()" size="3">Confirm by recipient</button>
           </ion-col>
```

```
ngOnInit() {
     
   this.storage.create();

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{

    if(user){
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid ).once('value',data=>{
     
          this.getprofile=data.val();
          console.log(this.getprofile);
       })
```

```
search(){
  
    const dbRef = firebase.database().ref('post/')
   
    firebase.database().ref('post/').on('value', data=>{

     dbRef.child("post").orderByChild("unitno").equalTo(this.getprofile.unitno);  
        
          this.postArray=Object.values(data.val());
          
          console.log(this.getprofile.unitno);  
          console.log(this.postArray);
       });
       }
```

[image]

[image]

**LATEST :**

```
  search(){
   
    firebase.database().ref('post/').orderByChild("unitno").on('value', data=>{  
      if(data.exists()){                                    
        this.postArray=Object.values(data.val());  
        this.result = this.postArray.filter(e=> e.unitno == this.getprofile.unitno)  
        console.log(this.result);
      }else{
        alert('No record found'); 
      } 
    });
```

[image]

Comment: `let result  = this.postArray.filter(e=> e.unitno == yourSearchVariable);`

Comment: may i know is this adding code ? if yes add to which line ?or replacement for which line?

Comment: this line actually updating your `postArray` variable. add this line to your search function.

Comment: i addded my html code to assign the value into table.

Comment: if i added this code

let result  = this.postArray.filter(e=> e.unitno == this.getprofile.unitno);  
May i know how to replace the ngFor* item ?

Comment: Hi @NajamUsSaqib

I try to add record exist validation by searching "unit no" , if record not found will return err msg. seen my code not work . can help to advise?
please refer to latest column

Comment: You can check array length in your html. 
`<ion-row *ngIf="result.length == 0" class="text-content">No Result Found</ion-row>`